# Android NoClassDefFoundError at OnDraw

Tags: android

I'm having a NoClassDefFoundError error at this line :

```
vto.addOnDrawListener(new OnDrawListener() {
```

On this code :

```
vto = visibleListView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnDrawListener(new OnDrawListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDraw() {
        Log.v("DRAWING", "DRAWN");

    }
});
```

Here is the error message :

```
12-23 21:38:49.068: E/AndroidRuntime(24508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 21:38:49.068: E/AndroidRuntime(24508): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.adylitica.activity.NotesActivity$14
12-23 21:38:49.068: E/AndroidRuntime(24508):    at com.adylitica.activity.NotesActivity.onStart(NotesActivity.java:1095)
12-23 21:38:49.068: E/AndroidRuntime(24508):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
```

Note that the NotesActivity class is the one I'm currently running the code above.

Ask for more details, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`OnDrawListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener.html) was Introduced in API level 16.

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND What are you trying to do in the `OnDrawListener`?

Comment: Knowing when my listView is completely drawn and filled up with the adapter in order to perform a screenshot of the updated listView.
Doing the updating and the screenshot right after is not gonna let the time to the listView to be updated (screenShot of an empty listView).

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND Can't you use `OnPreDrawListener`?

Comment: Totally works. Thanks a lot. Still I don't get why "OnPreDraw" triggers after the rendering.